# Intermediate model or manytomanyfield in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Currently i'm using a intermediate model for follow relationship in django as follows:-

```
class FollowingProfiles(models.Model):
    Profile=models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ProfileName=models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True,null=True)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ProfileName
```

while the profile model as follows:-

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,)
    Follwers=models.IntegerField(default='0')
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    bio=models.TextField(max_length=120,blank=True)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    private=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    verified=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ProfilePic=models.ImageField(upload_to='UserAvatar',blank=True,null=True)
    notif=models.BooleanField(default=False)#true when user have unread notification
    theme=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='normal')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

should i use `ManyToManyField` or that intermediate model? is there any downside of any of these approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with an Intermediate table, you will also need in future who is following whom. Like, say which are the users who are following my profile. So its transitive relationship between profile which you may need to chronicle in the Intermediate table.

How about putting that transitivity in this way:

```py
class Profile (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ##... other fields
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Follows(models.Model):
    following_to = models.ForeignKey(to=Profile, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="followed_to")
    followed_by = models.ForeignKey(to=Profile, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="followed_by")
```

so that you can also have who is following whom:

```sh
 % ./manage.py shell  
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from so.models import Profile, Follows 
>>> baseprofile = Profile.objects.create(name="Apple")
>>> profile1 = Profile.objects.create(name="Steve")
>>> profile2 = Profile.objects.create(name="Tim")
>>> follows1 = Follows.objects.create(following_to=baseprofile, followed_by=profile1)
>>> follows2 = Follows.objects.create(following_to=baseprofile, followed_by=profile2)
>>> baseprofile.followed_to.all()
<QuerySet [<Follows: Follows object (1)>, <Follows: Follows object (2)>]>
>>> print (*[p for p in baseprofile.followed_to.all()])
Follows object (1) Follows object (2)
>>>
```

So that now if you want to know who follows "Apple", you can find from this transitive relationship.

```
>>> print (*[p.followed_by.name for p in baseprofile.followed_to.all()],sep="\n")
Steve
Tim
```

Did this help? Were you looking for something similar?

If you are looking for strict normalization and reach till BCNF you might want to reconsider a sleek transition.

Comment: I want to know since i'm not using manytomanyfield , will it face a major time tradeoff in case if say a user is following 1k profiles?

Comment: According to me, many to many will bring more complexity than transitive relationships. You might want to check in with DB Normalisation to confirm that. If your keys are indexed, I don't think there should be a major issue with 1K profiles. For such structures, NoSQL would be a more preferable way to store.

Answer (score 3):

If there are other fields like status you have to use an intermediate model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,)
    follwers=models.ManyToMany('self', through=Followers)
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    bio=models.TextField(max_length=120,blank=True)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    private=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    verified=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='UserAvatar',blank=True,null=True)
    notif=models.BooleanField(default=False)#true when user have unread notification
    theme=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='normal')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Followers(models.Model):
    profile=models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile_set')
    follower=models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower_set')
    status=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: when i use your suggestion it's raising ` RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT` error

Comment: add related_name for foreign keys